# Is there a performance disadvantage for using bigger ints?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In order to *order* efficiently (`orderBy`), I am currently using very big integer values, almost reaching the [64-bit limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

Now, I am wondering: Does this makes *the queries run **any slower***?

I do not care about the few additional bytes for each query as 64 bits are the size of a single word stored as a string.

Basically, using these large numbers gives a nice sense of security for the future, i.e. a buffer because the numbers will be decreasing as more users use the application, but if it makes anything run more slowly, I would take performance instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnitude of a 64 bit integer isn't going to effectively change the performance characteristics of a large-scale sort on them.

Comment: That is awesome. I found large integers to be are a really nice way to circumvent the single field range filter limitation.

Comment: So are you partitioning the ranges of that integer field for some special purpose? I'm kind of curious what's the use case here.

Comment: It is a way to combine two different integer fields. You can concatenate the numbers as strings first and using very large numbers (or small, i.e. sub-zero), the left part will correspond to one integer field and the right to another, but the right one will not affect the left one as long as it is smaller than however many free bits there are. I am pretty sure that there is no better solution to combine two integer fields, but I would love to know!

Comment: Interesting, haven't heard of anyone trying that before!